# Как реализовать ограничение по кол-ву добавления клиентов на сайте

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli

Всем привет. Впервые на форуме, не судите строго если напишу неверно вопрос.

Проблема такая. На сайте реализован рейтинг пользователей "Мини, Партнер, Спонсор и Ген. спонсор". Пользователи при регистрации могут добавлять консультантов. При добавлении консультантов, у пользователя с определенным рейтингом должны быть ограничения по кол-ву создаваемых консультантов. Например при ранге "Мини" можно создать 3 консультантов. При ранге "спонсор" можно создать 5 консультантов.

Само создание консультантов завязано сильно на mysql.

Как реализовать данное ограничение? В PHP ещё не особо силен по знаниям)

Вот код который сейчас реализован

````
<div class="clearfix" > 
                  <span style="padding:10px;"></span>
                  </div>
   
                
            <div class="x_panel">
 
  <div class="col-xs-12" style="display: flex;">
                    <a style="float:left;margin: 10px; " href="/kons.php?action=new_form&rowformi=<?=$poisk?>" class="jsdelete_pers btn btn-warning btn-sm" >Добавить консультанта</a>
<!--                    <span class="input-text" ><b style="font-size:18px;color:#fff;"><?=$row1['N']?></b></span>
                   
                    <span style="background: lightblue;height: 34px;font-size:22px;font-weight: bold;color: red;margin-left: 5px;width: 100%"> <?=htmlspecialchars($row1['Имя_конс'])?>  </span> -->
 <?php $result444 = mysql_query ("SELECT count(`Долж_конс`) as count,`Долж_конс` FROM `medsoft` where `N`=".$poisk." and `Долж_конс` like 'medsoft%'", $db);
$rowcount = mysql_fetch_array($result444);

?>

                </div> 
                <div class="x_content">
                         
                    <div class="col-xs-6" style="margin-top:20px; margin-left: -15px;">
                        <table style="width: 208%;margin-left: 7px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 4%; padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px;">Код</td><td style="width: 3%">Готов</td><td style="width: 3%">Фото</td><td style="width: 13%;">ФИО</td><td style="width: 13%;">Должность</td><td style="width: 13%;">E-mail</td><td style="width: 13%;">Телефон</td><td style="width: 13%;">WhatsApp</td><td style="width: 20%;">Telegram</td></tr></table>


                      <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-left" >
                       <?php
                            $result_sys2 = mysql_query ("
                                 SELECT 
                                 `Сч_Выст`, 
                                 `N`,
                                 `Фото`,                                 
                                 `Код_конс`, 
                                 `Готов`,
                                 `ФИО_конс`,
                                 `Фам_конс`, 
                                 `Имя_конс`, 
                                 `Отч_конс`, 
                                 `Долж_конс`, 
                                 `Почт_конс`, 
                                 `Фот_конс`, 
                                 `Теле_конс`, 
                                 `Вац_конс`, 
                                 `Телег_конс` 
                                 FROM `medsoft` where `N`=".$poisk."  ORDER BY `Код_конс` asc", $db);

                            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_sys2)) {
                    



                                    //$row['Дата']= date("d.m.Y", strtotime(htmlspecialchars($row['Дата'])));
                                   // $row['Дата_обновл']= date("d.m.Y", strtotime(htmlspecialchars($row['Дата_обновл'])));         
                                    echo "<li class=''>";
                                    echo"<a href='#".$row['Сч_Выст']."' data-toggle='tab' aria-expanded='false' style='padding-top: 2px; color:#000;'><table class='table table-striped table-hover table-bordered' style='margin-bottom:0px;'>";
                                    echo"<thead><tr><th style='width: 4%;'>".$row['Код_конс']."</th><th style='width: 3%;'>".$row['Готов']."</th><th style='width: 3%;'>".$row['Фото']."</th><th style='width: 14%; text-align: left;'>".$row['ФИО_конс']."</th><th style='width: 14%; text-align: left;'>".$row['Долж_конс']."</th><th style='width: 14%; text-align: left;'>".$row['Почт_конс']."</th><th style='width: 14%; text-align: left;'>".$row['Теле_конс']."</th><th style='width: 14%; text-align: left;'>".$row['Вац_конс']."</th><th style='width: 14%; text-align: left;'>".$row['Телег_конс']."</th>"; //onMouseOver='f_over(this);' onMouseOut='f_out(this);'
                                    
                                    echo"";
                                    echo"";
                                     
                                    
                                   echo"<th style='width: 20px;'><a class='jsdelete' onclick='return confirm(\"Удалить Запись ?\");' href='/kons.php?action=del_form&rowformi=".$row['Сч_Выст']."'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'style='color:red;cursor:pointer;' title='Удалить' ></i></a></th></tr></thead></table></a>";
                                echo"</li>";
a:
                                }


                                ?>   
         
                          
                      </ul>
                    </div> 
    ```
````

Comment: *Как реализовать данное ограничение?* В зависимости от структуры хранения данных - констрейнтом либо триггером. И уж точно - делать это нужно не на стороне PHP.

Comment: @Akina а как реализовать тогда на другом языке. Например через js

Answer (score 0):

1. Не надо тулить ВСЁ в одно место.
2. база не должна быть источником логики, она только для выборки и вставки данных

---

Я бы решил примерно так:

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

final class Consultant
{
    // param ...
    // param ...
    // param ...
    // param ...
    
    
    // code ....
    // code ....
    // code ....
    // code ....
    // code ....
}
```

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

final class UserConsultants
{
    private $values;

    public function getAll(): array
    {
        return $this->values;
    }

    public function add(Consultant $consultant): void
    {
        if(!$this->has($consultant))
        {
            $this->values[] = $consultant;
        }
    }

    private function has(Consultant $consultant): bool
    {
        // какая-то логика по определению есть ли уже этот консультант или нет
    }

    public function count(): int
    {
        return count($this->values);
    }
}
```

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);


final class UserStatus extends \MyCLabs\Enum\Enum
{
    public const
        MINI = 'mini',
        PARTNER = 'partner',
        PARTNER2 = 'partner2',
        PARTNER3 = 'partner3',
        PARTNER4 = 'partner4',
        PARTNER5 = 'partner5';
}
```

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

final class User
{
    private UserStatus $status;
    private UserConsultants $consultants;
    // private ....
    // private ....
    // private ....
    // private ....
    // private ....
    // private ....

    public function __construct(
        UserStatus      $status,
        UserConsultants $consultants
        // $param,
        // $param,
        // $param,
        // $param,
    )
    {
        $this->status = $status;
        $this->consultants = $consultants;
    }

    // code ...
    // code ...
    // code ...
    // code ...
    // code ...

    public function addConsultant(Consultant $consultant): void
    {
        switch ($this->status->getValue()) {
            case UserStatus::MINI:
                $max = 3;
                break;
            case UserStatus::PARTNER:
                $max = 5;
                break;
            // ......
        }

        if ($this->consultants->count() > $max) {
            throw new DomainException('Максимальное число консультантов УЖЕ установлено');
        }

        $this->consultants->add($consultant);
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую этот метод

Comment: *база не должна быть источником логики, она только для выборки и вставки данных* Глупое утверждение. Любая обработка (даже элементарное связывание таблиц) - это логика. Контроль целостности - сплошная логика. Отказываться от всего этого? и всё потому, что разработчик знает свой язык, но ничего не понимает в SQL?

Comment: @Akina я имел ввиду, что код не должен сильно завязыватся на инфраструктуре. Вся логика приложения должна быть только, ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО в коде программы. А дополнительные механизмы, типа того же внешнего ключа естественно что могут, и даже должны быть. Но они должны быть ведомыми, а не ведущими

Comment: *Вся логика приложения должна быть только, ИСКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО в коде программы.* Странное утверждение... Вы используете кучу внешней логики (системные библиотеки, процедуры фреймворка и пр.), и как-то это вас не парит совершенно. Ну право слово, дурь же - писать свою собственную процедуру, скажем, сортировки, когда есть библиотечная, правда? так какая разница? Здесь точно так же, сделал процедуру контроля, отладил, вынес её во внешний модуль - и пользуйся. И нет никакой разницы между структурой таблицы и процедурой или триггером, их-то ты в код не пихаешь, создал таблицу и пользуешь...