# Как ограничить добавление пользователей

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, mysqli

Всем привет. Есть проблема. Нужно ограничить число добавления пользователей с привязкой к БД.

На сайте реализовано добавление пользователей. Нужно чтобы клиент при добавлении пользователя был ограничен на кол-во добавления через ранг.

На сайте реализованы ранги "Мини, Эконом, Стандарт, Партнер, Спонсор, Ген. спонсор"

У каждого ранга должно быть ограничение на добавление пользователя. У "Мини" 3 шт.   У "Эконом" 4 шт. У "Стандарт" 5 шт.   У "Партнера" 6 шт.  У "Спонсор" 8 шт  и у "Ген спонсор" 10 шт.

Как сделать, чтобы органичение было привязано к рангу.

Код кнопки

```
<div class="col-xs-12" style="display: flex;">
                    <a style="float:left;margin: 10px; " href="/kons.php?action=new_form&rowformi=<?=$poisk?>" class="jsdelete_pers btn btn-warning btn-sm" >Добавить консультанта</a>
<!--                    <span class="input-text" ><b style="font-size:18px;color:#fff;"><?=$row1['N']?></b></span>
                   
                    <span style="background: lightblue;height: 34px;font-size:22px;font-weight: bold;color: red;margin-left: 5px;width: 100%"> <?=htmlspecialchars($row1['Имя_конс'])?>  </span> -->
 <?php $result444 = mysql_query ("SELECT count(`Долж_конс`) as count,`Долж_конс` FROM `medsoft` where `N`=".$poisk." and `Долж_конс` like 'medsoft%'", $db);
$rowcount = mysql_fetch_array($result444);

?>
Скрыты ранее занесенные medsoft MedSoft-*: <?=$rowcount['count']?> шт.

                </div>
```

Вот так выглядит таблица Ранг

```
id   rang   Описание

1     6      Мини
2     5      Эконом
3     4      Стандарт
4     3      Партнер
5     2      Спонсор
6     1      Генспонсор
```

Comment: Не совсем понят к чему привязан ранг, если к клиенту то смотрим какой у пользователя ранг, потом смотрим сколько пользователей он уже добавил и если кол-во пользователей равно кол-ву рангу, то клиенту отдает ошибку что лимит исчерпан

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Как реализовать ограничение по кол-ву добавления клиентов на сайте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1372071/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d1%83-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5)

Comment: @Евгений Гаврилов ранг привязан к клиенту, но как выше я написал там идет ограничение до 10 добавлений, а рангов всего 6

Comment: @ Akina да вопрос тот же, но я его немного по другому указал, т.к. на тот ответов не было особо, да и я там указал в большинстве привязку к PHP, хотя можно сделать и через JS (если конечно можно)

Comment: Вам не плохой ответ дали в предыдущем вопросе. А что касается насчет хранения логики в базе ее держать в виде хранимых процедур или реализовывать ее на стороне php, это уже вам решать. Я бы реализовал ее на стороне php, т. к. все "яйца" в одной корзине. Через JS делать не надо, т. к. сервер будет не защищен и любым REST клиентом можно надобавлять сколько угодно консультантов.

Comment: @Евгений Гаврилов Хорошо.